# Riemann's $\zeta$ function and the uniform distribution on $[-1,0]$

Tags: bernoulli-numbers, riemann-zeta-function, probability-distributions

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64566/riemanns-zeta-function-and-the-uniform-distribution-on-1-0

Stackexchange isn't getting really excited about this, so here it is.

The $n$th cumulant of the uniform probability distribution on the interval $[-1,0]$ is $B_n/n$, where $B_n$ is the $n$th Bernoulli number.

And $-\zeta(1-n)=B_n/n$, where $\zeta$ is Riemann's function.

Those two facts can be derived, but is there some argument that shows, without doing that, that you'd *expect* the cumulants of the uniform distribution to be those values of the $\zeta$ function?

Might this shed some light either on the $\zeta$ function or the uniform distribution?  Or anything else?

**Appendix:** Cumulants are like moments, but better.  The $n$th cumulant of a probability distribution is homogeneous of degree $n$ (like the $n$th moment).  If $n=1$ it is shift-equivariant; if $n>1$ it is shift-invariant (like the $n$th *central* moment).  If $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ are independent random variables, then the $n$th cumulant of the distribution of their sum is just the sum of the $n$th cumulants of their distributions.  That last property is shared by central moments only in the cases $n=2,3$ (where the cumulant is just the central moment).  Simplest nontrivial example: the 4th cumulant is the fourth central moment minus 3 times the square of the second central moment.

**Later addition (should this be a separate question?):** The number of independent Bernoulli trials strictly preceding the first success, with probability $1/(1+c)$ of success on each trial, is a geometrically distributed random variable with expected value $c$, taking values in the set $\lbrace 0,1,2,\ldots \rbrace$.  The first several cumulants of that distribution are these
$$
\begin{align}
& c \\
& c+c^2 \\
& c + 3c^2 + 2c^3 \\
& c + 7c^2 + 12c^3 + 6c^4 \\
& c + 15c^2 + 50c^3 + 60c^4 + 24c^5 \\
& c + 32c^2 +180c^3+390c^4+360c^5+120c^6
\end{align}
$$
The probability distribution of the number of successes in just one trial, with probability $c$ of success on each trial, has cumulants
$$
\begin{align}
& c \\
& c-c^2 \\
& c - 3c^2 + 2c^3 \\
& c - 7c^2 + 12c^3 - 6c^4 \\
& c - 15c^2 + 50c^3 - 60c^4 + 24c^5 \\
& c - 32c^2 +180c^3-390c^4+360c^5-120c^6
\end{align}
$$
They're the same except for alternating signs.

If it were possible for the probability to be $-c$, where $c>0$, this sequence would be just $-1$ times the sequence of cumulants of the geometric distribution.  Likewise, the sequence of values of $\zeta(1-n)$ is $-1$ times the sequence of cumulants of the probability distribution specified above.  Could $\zeta(1-n),\quad n=1,2,3,\ldots$ be the sequence of cumulants of a distribution that would exist if we allowed negative probabilities (but still required the measure of the whole probability space to be $1$)?

If so, do we have two instances of a phenomenon that can be stated in a general way?

Answer (score 9):

$X$ is the uniform distribution on $[-1,0]$, so the moment generating function of $X$ is 
$$E(e^{tX})=\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{k}\left(1+e^{-t/k}+\dots+e^{-(k-1)t/k}\right)=\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{k}\frac{1-e^{-t}}{1-e^{-t/k}}=\frac{1-e^{-t}}{t}$$
The cumulant generating function is the logarithm of this, call it $g(t)$.  It'll be easier to compute the Taylor series of $tg'(t)+1$:
$$tg'(t)+1=-\frac{t}{1-e^t}=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty te^{kt}=-t\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{k^nt^{n}}{n!}$$
Rearrange the order of summation:
$$tg'(t)+1=-t\sum_{n=0}^\infty \zeta(-n)\frac{t^n}{n!}$$
Now compare coefficients on either side:  the $n$th cumulant of $X$ is plainly $-\zeta(1-n)$.

What?  Why are you looking at me like that?

Comment: But does this really answer the OP's question? 

Comment: Can anyone tell me the meaning or apropos of the last line (two questions)? I need to develop my sense of humor.

Comment: I had in my mind a scene where I am presenting this bogus argument on a blackboard to a skeptical, wincing audience. 